# pass JSON to jsp from Spring controller. How represent JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to represent JSON in table. I get JSON from my controller and i don`t know what next...How can i pass JSON to exact jsp or i should not do it?Sorry, I m new in JSON.
And what should i do after method add(...)? What should i return.
Here is my controller code

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private ClientLogManager clientLogManager;

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/getlog/{appId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<ClientLog> getAll(@PathVariable Integer appId, Model model) {
    List clientLogs = clientLogManager.get(appId);
    return clientLogs;
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/log", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ClientLog add(@RequestBody ClientLog clientLog) {
    clientLogManager.add(clientLog);
    return clientLog;
}
```

}

Comment: I googled about 3 hours, really. I m not that type of people that ask without any work by theirself. 
May be, you dont understand me.

Comment: have a look at this SO, does that help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927823/how-to-consume-json-webservice-from-java-client

Comment: Your link tells about passing JSON to controller. I need pass json FROM controller.

Comment: did that new link help you out?

Answer (score 0):

u can get your json data via a simple html file ...

in your jsp file you can get this list with jQuery

```
  $.getJSON('localhost:8080/api/getlog/12', function (clientlogs) {
        for(clientlog : clientlogs){
            console.log(clientlog.id);
        }
    });
```

if u have a save operation you had better use PUT method

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/log", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ClientLog add(@RequestBody ClientLog clientLog) {
    clientLogManager.add(clientLog);
    return clientLog;
}
```